# Construct a permutation matrix from some eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues, permutations, eigenvector, orthogonal-matrices

Given $n$ orthonormal vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb R^d$, where $d > n$, we can show that there are many orthogonal matrices $X$ of size $d$ such that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are eigenvectors of $X$ corresponding to either eigenvalues $1$ or $-1$ of $X$. For example, pick a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ of size $d$, whose diagonal contains only $\pm 1$, then complete the basis for $v_1, ..., v_n$ (for example, by Gram-Schmidt process) and form an orthogonal matrix $V$ of size $d$. Then $X = V \Sigma V^T$ is one orthogonal matrix we look for.

Can we verify that, amongst those matrices, there is any nontrivial permutation matrix (i.e. different from identity)?

Comment: A permutation $P$ matrix can be viewed (up to block permutation) as a direct sum of cycles. The eigenvectors of $P$ are thus well known. The only cycle with real eigenvalues and eigenvectors is the transposition. So in your question a non trivial permutation $P=X$ exist with eigenvectors $v_i$  when only two entries of $v_i$ are non zero and of the same modulus.

Comment: @ToniMhax: I think you are assuming $n=d$ at the end of your comment. For small $n$, it's quite possible that we can produce permutation matrices (in a trivial way) that are simply the identity on the $v_j$'s.

Comment: That is also the typical situation: Most vectors will not be a multiple of their permutations (of order $2$, here, to make matters worse), so we are forced to set $Xv_j=v_j$ and then hope for the possibility of a non-trivial permutation on $\{v_j\}^{\perp}$.

Comment: thanks for your comments. @ChristianRemling: can you elaborate more on this comment: For small , it's quite possible that we can produce permutation matrices (in a trivial way) that are simply the identity on the $v_j$'s

Comment: @SiXUlm: I was simply trying to say that if for example $\{ v_1,\ldots, v_n\}^{\perp}$ contains a two-dimensional subspace spanned by unit vectors $e_k$, then we can take an $X$ of block form that swaps those $e_k$ and is the identity on the orthogonal complement (which includes the $v_j$).